# Adding unknown exception to your try catch

Tags: python-3.x, exception

I have a piece of code that checks for a particular exception:

```
while ser.in_waiting:
        try:
            ser_bytes = ser.readline()
            ser_bytes = ser_bytes.decode("utf-8")
            text.insert("end", ser_bytes)
        except UnicodeExceptionError:
            print("UnicodeExceptionError")
```

However, i received this error:

```
    except UnicodeExceptionError:
NameError: name 'UnicodeExceptionError' is not defined
```

Can i also add another exception to my block of code, that will target all exceptions that are not `UnicodeExceptionError`?

Comment: The problem is that `UnicodeExceptionError` isn't defined. Do you mean `UnicodeDecodeError`? But for the question, yes, you can simply add another `except` under the one you already have.

Comment: Perhaps you wanted `UnicodeDecodeError` instead of `UnicodeExceptionError`?

Comment: Thank you guys. You are right! Such a dumb omission.